# Interface and generic constraint performance gap

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to figure out the difference between interface and generic constraint.

If there is any difference, is there also a difference in performance?

Consider the following snippet:

```
interface IBase {
    aNumber: number
}

class ConcreteA implements IBase {
    aNumber = 1
}

class ConcreteB implements IBase {
    aNumber = 2
}

function interfaceFunction(param: IBase) {
    console.log(param.aNumber)
}

function genericFunction<T extends IBase>(param: T) {
    console.log(param.aNumber)
}

const a = new ConcreteA()
const b = new ConcreteB()

interfaceFunction(a)
interfaceFunction(b)
genericFunction(a)
genericFunction(b)
```

I think both interfaceFunction and genericFunction are valid functions to take IBase typed data as a parameter.

Which is a preferable way to write a TypeScript function?

Is there a general coding convention that is more common?

How do these two functions differ in terms of performance?

In Swift, genericFunction tends to perform better due to not requiring peeking on protocol witness table. In TypeScript, what is going on under the hood?

Comment: TypeScript does not exist at runtime, the type metadata is erased in transpilation to leave only JS. Do you mean the performance _of transpilation_?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to ask a single well-defined question, and provide enough details about what you're asking in that one question so that people can answer with some objectively verifiable response ("preferable" is subjective, and "performance" could refer to either the TypeScript compiler or the runtime code, so it's ambiguous).

Answer (score 1):

It is the same in your case, type system includes generic are removed after compile like this:

```js
function interfaceFunction(param) {
    console.log(param.aNumber)
}

function genericFunction(param) {
    console.log(param.aNumber)
}
```

so their performance (at runtime) are the same.

---

the difference of these two ways to declare function is showed when the return type is related with input parameter, see this example:

```
interface IBase {
    aNumber: number
}

class ConcreteA implements IBase {
    aNumber = 1
    aString = "string"
}

function interfaceFunction(param: IBase) {
    return param
}

function genericFunction<T extends IBase>(param: T) {
    return param
}

const a = new ConcreteA()

const result1 = interfaceFunction(a)
const result2 = genericFunction(a)

result1.aString // ERROR Property 'aString' does not exist on type 'IBase'.
result2.aString // works
```

the function declare with generic keeps the original type of the input, and the other doesn't.